# How to wrap too long title in DropdownButton from react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button, however, its (dynamically changed) title may be too long to fit. Thus, I am wondering whether there is a way to automatically wrap the too long title to the 2nd line?

```
  <Panel >
       <Panel.Body collapsible>

           <ButtonGroup vertical >

                    dsadas
                    <DropdownButton title="Dropdown2re12r412r12r12r2r2">
                        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                    </DropdownButton>
                    fwf21
                    <DropdownButton title="Dropdown" >
                        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
                    </DropdownButton>

            </ButtonGroup>
        </Panel.Body>
    </Panel>
```

Edit: added screenshot [image]

Comment: Could you provide a working example? This should be easy to tackle via CSS

Comment: @konekoya I edited the question with more details and a screenshot. Could you plz have a look?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have posted my answer, check that out!

Answer (score 0):

Add navItem='true' to your dropdownBotton tag

Comment: Nothing changed besides this error: Warning: React does not recognize the `navItem` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `navitem` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to wrap them as the following:

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

- `width: 100px`: set a specific width, so the wrapping works.
- `white-space: normal`: this line overrides the styles: `white-space: nowrap`
  coming from Bootstrap which makes your button text not wrapping.
- `word-break: break-all`: break the words, you can learn more from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Note if it's not working, often it's because of the CSS specificity. Your styles are probably overridden by Bootstrap. You can always check this in your browser's developer tools.